# Why f1 is found but f2 not?

Tags: c++, friend-function

Following codes are in two source files.

First:

```
namespace A {
    // two friends; neither is declared apart from a friend declaration
    // these functions implicitly are members of namespace A
    class C {
        friend void f2();           // won’t be found, unless otherwise declared
        friend void f1(const C&);   // found by argument-dependent lookup
    };
}
int main()
{
    A::C obj;
    f1(obj);        // ok: find A::f through the friend declaration in A::C
    A::f2();        // no member named f2 in namespace A
}
```

and the second:

```
#include <iostream>
namespace A {
    class C;
    void f1(const C&) {
        std::cout << 1;
    }
    void f2() {
        std::cout << 2;
    }
}
```

The first piece of code is copied from C++ primer, the only difference is C++ primer call **f2()** without prefix the namespace. The second piece is my complement. I wanna know now that **f1** and **f2** implicitly are members of namespace A, why **A::f2()** is still wrong while **f1(obj)** can be found by ADL?

Comment: First time I've come across ADL... my reaction would roughly be "OHMYGODWHY".

Comment: @Cubic so that `std::cout << 'x';` works. Without ADL you would have to write either `using std::operator<<`, or `std::operator<<(std::cout, 'x');` etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the rule, found in 7.3.1.2, that causes `A::f2()` to fail:

> If a friend declaration in a non-local class first declares a class, function, class template or function template the friend is a member of the innermost enclosing namespace. The friend declaration does not by itself make the name visible to unqualified lookup (3.4.1) or qualified lookup (3.4.3).

Comment: i still confused why f1 is found by ADL but f2 not? is there any difference between them? or, from the last sentence of your excerpt, just because f1 is found by ADL?

Comment: @xlnwel: Yes, the ADL rules allow finding things that cannot be found by name.

Answer (score 0):

In the first block of code, `f2` is in the lexical scope of `A::C`, i.e. the name is visible within the scope of `A::C`. It is not visible outside `A::C`.

To make `f2` visible outside the scope of `A::C`, you'll need to declare or define it in `A`.

Comment: `f1` is found by ADL. Since `f2` does not have any argument, ADL cannot be used to find `f2`.